# Do unused gems in Gemfile take memory in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundle

This might be a stupid question:

If I add a gem in Gemfile (and bundle install) and don't use it in the rails application, does it affect the consumed memory size? Usually I use my application template which has all the gems that I might use. I fear that it might consume memory unnecessarily.

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All gems are loaded on the rails startup. You must to add `require: false` to don't load the gems at start and require it manualy. Your boot time will be slower if you have many unused gems in your Gemfile.

Comment: Where would I put the require: false ?

Comment: In your Gemfile you must to have this : `gem 'my-gem', require: false`

Comment: Only boot time or does it also have an impact on performances?

Comment: Load more things take more memory so, load unecessary files will slow down the app but I think it's not a big problem. You have a lot of optimization to do before to think to that.